# Computing possible formulas (expressions) from input data set

Tags: algorithm, search, dataset, data-science

I am new in dealing to with large data sets, I got a problem where there are expressions (formulas like  A = B + C) in a List-1 and variables of the expression may have different possible values (C = D*3 , C = B/2 , B = D*50, etc) in List-2. Then List-3 has constant values for the variables ( B , D, etc). I need to compute all the possible results for the expression ( Like A may have two different results for each value of C). 
The possible combination can be huge!

I planning to break-down the problem as follows - 
1. For each expression in List-1 look up all possible values for each variable in List-2 and 
Generate all possible expression in List-4. List-4 can be huge , may be in GB or TB!

2. Create a tree for each expression from first generated list
3. Find the each variable values in List-3
4. Replace constant in the expression to get the result.

Step 1 and 3 are the core problems which needs lot of memory and CPU, any guidance would be highly appreciated.

List1: Expressions , for example - A = x + y, y = u + v

List2: contains possible extensions for operands of formulas in List1 
 - for example: v = 20 + u, v = 30*u

List3: constant values – for example:  x = 10, u = 50

A = x + y, y = u + 20 + u, x = 20, u = 10 => y = 40, A = 60
A = x + y, y = u + 30*u, x = 20, u = 10 => y = 310, A = 330

Comment: I think you do not have to save all the combination in the memory. Just get each combination, process and save them out. If it is too slow, you can split list-1 into different parts and process each part in parallel.

Comment: Can you give a small, consistent, representative list of sample data?

Comment: Use a dtnamic language and expression evaluation.

Comment: Sorry guys I missed to add sample data of lists.

Comment: Is `A = x + y, y = u + v` one expression or two? Are there any free variables in `List1` bound in `List1`? same for `List2`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want some kind of `Expression` type, with the usual `Add`, `Multiply`, `Constant` etc sub-types, plus `BoundVariable` and `FreeVariable`.

`Expression` would have an operation that takes a `BoundVariable` and substitutes it's body for all the instances of that `FreeVariable`.

```
interface Expression : Equatable<Expression>
{   
    Expression subsitute(BoundVariable bound);
    Option<Value> evaluate(); // only expression with no free variables have a value
    // maybe a freeVariables, or a toString or whatever else is useful
}

class BoundVariable
{
    Expression body;
    Identifier name;
}

class FreeVariable : Expression
{
    Identifier name;
    Expression subsitute(BoundVariable bound)
    {
        return name == bound.name ? bound.body : this;
    }
    Option<Value> evaluate()
    {
        return new Option<Value>(); // None
    }
    bool Equals (Expression other)
    {
        if (other as FreeVariable) 
        {
            return name == other.name;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Add : Expression
{
    Expression left;
    Expression right;
    Expression subsitute(BoundVariable bound)
    {
        return new Add(left.substitute(bound), right.substitute(bound));
    }
    Option<Value> evaluate()
    {
        return from l in left.evaluate()
               from r in right.evaluate()
               select l + r;
    }
    bool Equals (Expression other)
    {
        if (other as Add) 
        {
            return left.Equals(other.left) && right.Equals(other.right);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

// Multiply, Subtract, Divide etc.
// It may be easier to have a bunch of wrappers for (binary) Function<Value, Value, Value> (unary) Function<Value, Value>, etc.

class Literal : Expression
{
    Value value;
    Expression subsitute(BoundVariable bound)
    {
        return this;
    }
    Option<Value> evaluate()
    {
        return value;
    }
    bool Equals (Expression other)
    {
        if (other as Literal) 
        {
            return value == other.value;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then just loop through the cartesian product of your lists, outputing identifiers with evaluated expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your statements are valid Python statements then the following could be adapted to give the output you want. At the moment it just prints the variables with their final values from the calculations:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Organse the lists input as sets of simultaneous expressions:
expr_sets_list = ['A = x + y, y = u + 20 + u, x = 20, u = 10',
         'A = x + y, y = u + 30*u, x = 20, u = 10' ]

for expr_set_string in expr_sets_list:
    # Split into individual expressions on the comma separators
    exprs = [expr.strip() for expr in expr_set_string.split(',')]
    variables = {}  # Accumulates variables and their values
    for statement in reversed(exprs): # expressions WILL execute in reverse
        exec(statement, {},  variables)
    #
    print('\n%r =>' % expr_set_string)
    pp(variables)
```

Output:

```
'A = x + y, y = u + 20 + u, x = 20, u = 10' =>
{'A': 60, 'u': 10, 'x': 20, 'y': 40}

'A = x + y, y = u + 30*u, x = 20, u = 10' =>
{'A': 330, 'u': 10, 'x': 20, 'y': 310}
```